# Strong Parameters: Permit an array of symbols

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters

I need to whitelist a long list of params for a form in my Rails app. I've made an array of symbols, each symbol having the name of a param I need to whitelist. Is there a way I can pass this array into the permit method and have those params permitted? The form does not pass the params as a hash.

**form.rb**

```
class Form < ApplicationRecord

  jsonb_accessor :fields,
                 salutation: :string, # personal info
                 first_name: :string,
                 last_name: :string,
                 birthday: :string,
                 marital_status: :string,
                 number_of_dependants: :string,
                 first_time_owner: :string,
                 spouse_deal: :string,
                 phone_cell: :string, # contact info
                ...

      def self.fields
        [:salutation, :first_name, :last_name,
         :birthday,
         :marital_status,
         :number_of_dependants,
         :first_time_owner,
         :spouse_deal,
         :phone_cell,
         :phone_home,
        ...
        ]
      end

end
```

**forms_controller.rb**

```
  def form_params
    params.require(:form).permit(:name, Form.fields)
  end
```

I'm using the jsonb_accessor gem to store these fields in a JSON column in the Form table. So I'll have a lot of different forms, each with different params. So I need to find a way to dynamically permit parameters. I think the above might be an OK solution. Though I'd appreciate advice on a better solution.

Comment: `params.require(:form).permit(:name, fields: [])`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `Form.fields` returns an array of symbols, you can just splat it out to turn them into individual arguments:

```
params.require(:form).permit(:name, *Form.fields)
```

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason it's only permitting `:birthday`. No idea why.

Comment: Hm, you want to call `Form.fields` as a class method, but your code shows you defined it as an instance method (which to the best of my understanding would also clash with `fields` defined by `jsonb_accessor`, though I never used that gem).

Comment: Nevermind, I had an attr_accessor at the top of my model which was overriding the fields object. Thanks again!